# vhosts with various hosts and http/https

Tags: apache-2.2, http, https, virtualhost, configuration

I have the file underneath in my vhosts.d directory and it's called hosts.conf (from what I gather the name isn't a problem). Now there are various hosts as you can see, if I use http (port 80) no problems at all I can bounce form one website to the other, but if I use https (port 443) whatever website I type in my browser i always end up in the website that is first listed with the 443 port (in this case mobile-dev1.***.it). Obviously my real file doesn't have *** written but the proper website name.

```
<VirtualHost 10.65.200.7:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/www/htdocs/public"
    ServerName portal.***.it
    <Directory "/srv/www/htdocs/public">
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.65.200.7:80>
DocumentRoot /srv/mobile-dev1/public
ServerName mobile-dev1.***.it
<Directory /srv/mobile-dev1/public>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.65.200.7:443>
DocumentRoot /srv/mobile-dev1/public
ServerName mobile-dev1.***.it
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_***_it.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard_***_it.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/RapidSSLCA.crt
<Directory /srv/mobile-dev1/public>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>

<VirtualHost 10.65.200.7:80>
DocumentRoot /srv/mobile-dev2/public
ServerName mobile-dev2.***.it
<Directory /srv/mobile-dev2/public>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.65.200.7:443>
DocumentRoot /srv/mobile-dev2/public
ServerName mobile-dev2.***.it
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_***_it.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard_***_it.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/RapidSSLCA.crt
<Directory /srv/mobile-dev2/public>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.65.200.7:80>
DocumentRoot /srv/mobile-test/public
ServerName mobile-test.***.it
<Directory /srv/mobile-test/public>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.65.200.7:443>
DocumentRoot /srv/mobile-test/public
ServerName mobile-test.***.it
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard_***_it.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard_***_it.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/RapidSSLCA.crt
<Directory /srv/mobile-test/public>
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for any help, the problem is driving me mad as it will likely be something simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things spring to mind:

- You don't have a `NameVirtualHosts` directive.  It might be in one of your other config files, but you'll need `NameVirtualHosts 10.65.200.7:443` somewhere for this to work.
- You might be using a browser that doesn't support [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).  If memory serves, no version of IE under XP supports SNI.  You need this because you have several SSL vhosts that share an IP address, and the only way the webserver can differentiate between them is by using SNI.

Comment: I'm using firefox under windows 7 so shouldn't be a SNI problem. I need to look into the NameVitrualHosts thing, should it be in my hosts file or somewhere else?

Comment: ok it was the namevirtualhosts directive, thanks a lot!!